# Abstract classes and Interface where exactly it is used in selenium framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I know that Interfaces are used for full implementation of methods or 100% abstraction and 
Abstract classes for partial abstraction which can contain abstract methods and non abstract methods or both.
But where exactly these concepts are used in selenium framework ?

Answer (score 0):

If we want to launch a browser (e.g. Firefox/Chrome), we will write the following syntax in Java

```
// FireFox
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
// Chrome
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

We never write `WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();`

Because here [`WebDriver` (JavaDocs)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.50.0/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html)is an interface and all the methods implemented in `FirefoxDriver`and `ChromeDriver`.

Selenium's `AbstractWebDriverEventListener` is an abstract class, where we can implement definition for only required methods.

Use this class as base class, if you want to implement a `WebDriverEventListener` and are only interested in some events. All methods provided by this class have an empty method body.

Source : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/AbstractWebDriverEventListener.html